# Include HTML From Sub-Folder Site

Tags: php

I have two sites, one stored  in the root of server, another in a sub-folder as shown below.

```
SITE ONE
ROOT/index.php
ROOT/assets/includes/header.php - contains styles and scripts

SITE TWO
ROOT/SUB-FOLDER/index.php
ROOT/SUB-FOLDER/assets/includes/header.php - contains styles and scripts
```

I am using PHP includes in order to include external files where the first site works fine using the code below, however the second one don't:

```
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/assets/includes/header.php');
```

Could you please help me to achieve similar result for the site stored in the SUB-FOLDER.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,  in the paths you showed, the root project has an assets directory but the subfolder doesn't. Is it a mistake?

Comment: Yes, did a mistake. Fixed :)

Comment: I'm on my phone at the moment and not had the time to test this, but does it work if you replace $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] with __DIR__ ?

Comment: Sorry formatting error. With 2 underscores on both sides of DIR

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. ROOT/SUB-FOLDER/index.php opens fine, but the any sub-page such as ROOT/SUB-FOLDER/sub-folder2/other-page.php does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the include link to:

```
include('assets/includes/header.php');
```

and adding the

```
<base href="http://example.com/SUB-FOLDER">
```

tag to head of the included pages solved the my issue.